# Jquery Clone specific tag

Tags: jquery, clone

I am trying to echo the content within a h6 tag, based on:

```
$('input').keyup( function () {
if ($(this).val() > '0') 
    $('#testh6').append($(this).parents("tr").clone("h6"));
});
```

The problem is, that it takes the entire tr not just the containing h6. How can I modify this, so I just clone the h6?

Comment: Although the answer below is probably right, it would help to have an example of the html you are trying to manipulate...

Comment: The second jquery code example in here http://api.jquery.com/clone/ `$('.hello').clone().appendTo('.goodbye');`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('input').keyup( function () {
if ($(this).val() > '0') 
    $('#testh6').append($(this).parents("tr").find("h6").clone());
});
```

**EDIT**: Answer to comment:

To remove it again when val == 0

```
$('input').keyup( function () {
    if ($(this).val() > '0') {
        $('#testh6 h6').remove();  // Make sure there's no previous tag left.
        $('#testh6').append($(this).parents("tr").find("h6").clone());
    }
    elseif ($(this).val() == '0'){
        $('#testh6 h6').remove();
    }
});
```

This will of course remove all h6-tags in that div, if that's not what you want you need to keep a reference or somehow identify it so you can recuperate it later

Comment: Awesome - thankyou! Do you know how to remove it from the div if the input goes back to 0?

Comment: If you want to completely remove it from the DOM, use `.remove()`

Comment: @Kenneth - that revised comment does not seem to work for me? Also, my problem is if they change their answer multiple times in the input, it clones the h6 tag everytime - basically as long as the input is not 0, it should only show the corresponding h6 content once.

Comment: The quick and dirty way of doing this would be the clear the previously added h6 before adding a new one. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Kenneth - great, except the script doesnt do anything now. If I just use your original clone it works, but the revision you did does not place any content nor remove any content from the div.

Comment: Probably your original h6 is also located inside the testh6 div and thus the .remove() is removing the original. Could you check that?

Comment: @Kenneth - nope, the testh6 div is blank.

Comment: Hmm, if you could provide us the html-code we can see what's really happening

Comment: @Kenneth - Sure, you can see a sample of the HTML plus your script at:
http://pastie.org/7578750

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28248/discussion-between-palemo-and-kenneth)